# How does Continuous-Data export determine Ingestion time in case the input is a query

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Whenever a continuous-export entity is defined, it has a query as its input. If the query is just a table name, it is easy to understand how the export takes place. Ingestion time of records in the table must be getting considered with respect to different points in time when the export entity runs. But what if the query is the actual 'query' , I mean say some transformation is being applied on top of the table with various pipe operators. In that case the result of the query is dynamic and the data is not going to get Ingested anywhere. Does it mean that continuous-export really only considers Ingestion time of the leftmost entity in the query, which is obviously going to be some table and so obviously does have Ingestion time stored as part of its records.

**UPDATE**

Adding this update as I need more clarification on @yifat's answer.

So lets say my query refers to the three tables t1, t2, t3. I have created the following diagram to depict my confusion:-

[image]

As you can see in the diagram, current run instance will anyway ensure that it will get data for all the 3 tables since the last exported cursor. So how does adding forcedLatency make difference? The diagram will illustrate something that I have not understood correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous export saves the last exported database cursor, and each continuous export job considers only the records ingested since that database cursor. This applies to *all* tables referenced by the query, regardless of how many and which operators the query includes. Due to this, if your query includes a join, it's recommended to set the forcedLatency option to the max expected latency of tables participating in the join.

For instance, assume the query *inner* joins table T1 with table T2 on key K, and you expect records for same K in both tables to arrive around the same time. Now assume that at time t0, there's an ingestion to T1 with key K1, at time t2 there's an ingestion to T2 with key K1 and continuous export runs in between, at time t1. In this case, the export will miss K1 in the result set, since is executes an inner join and T2 doesn't have K1 yet. The next export cycle won't include this record either, since it will only include records that were ingested after t1 which don't include K1 in T1. Forced latency forces some delay on the cursor, such that only records older than ForcedLatency are included. In this example records in T1 will "wait" for records in T2.

If the export query contains a single table, there's no need for forcedLatency.
If you do not wish for all tables to be scoped to the database cursor, you can use the 'over' parameter to specify which tables should be considered. This is useful if you're joining with a dimension table and would like each query to consider *all* records.

Comment: @yaifats sorry it is slightly confusing. So can we say that if the query is a single table, there is no need of specifying forcedLatency?

Comment: I edited my answer and provided an example. I hope this clarifies it.